# Azure ML - How do I fix this Snapshot Exception?

Tags: python, azureml-python-sdk

I'm doing a pipeline in Azure ML SDK. After I had run the pipeline for some amount of times it reported I had reached the Snapshot limit of 300MB. I followed some of the fixes that was proposed:

- Each step script is moved to a separate subfolder
- I added a datastore to the pipeline
- This line was added: `azureml._restclient.snapshots_client.SNAPSHOT_MAX_SIZE_BYTES = 1000`

But then a new Snapshot error occurred after I submitted my pipeline:

```
pipeline1 = Pipeline(default_source_directory=".", default_datastore=def_blob_store, workspace=ws, steps=[prep_step, hd_step, register_model_step])
```

THE ERROR MESSAGE:

```
    WARNING:root:If 'script' has been provided here and a script file name has been specified in 'run_config', 'script' provided in ScriptRunConfig initialization will take precedence.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SnapshotException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-05c5aa4991aa> in <module>
----> 1 pipeline1 = Pipeline(default_source_directory=".", default_datastore=def_blob_store, workspace=ws, steps=[prep_step, hd_step, register_model_step])
      2 pipeline1.validate()
      3 pipeline_run = Experiment(ws, 'health_insuarance').submit(pipeline1, regenerate_outputs=False)
      4 RunDetails(pipeline_run).show()

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/_experiment_method.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     95             """
     96             ExperimentSubmitRegistrar.register_submit_function(self.__class__, submit_function)
---> 97             return init_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     98         return wrapper
     99     return real_decorator

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/pipeline.py in __init__(self, workspace, steps, description, default_datastore, default_source_directory, resolve_closure, _workflow_provider, _service_endpoint, **kwargs)
    175                 raise ValueError('parameter %s is not recognized for Pipeline ' % key)
    176         self._enable_email_notification = enable_email_notification
--> 177         self._graph = self._graph_builder.build(self._name, steps, finalize=False)
    178 
    179     def _set_experiment_name(self, name):

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py in build(self, name, steps, finalize, regenerate_outputs)
   1479                 pass
   1480 
-> 1481         graph = self.construct(name, steps)
   1482         if finalize:
   1483             graph.finalize(regenerate_outputs=regenerate_outputs)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py in construct(self, name, steps)
   1501         self._graph = Graph(name, self._context)
   1502         self._nodeStack.append([])
-> 1503         self.process_collection(steps)
   1504         for builder in self._builderStack[::-1]:
   1505             builder.apply_rules()

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py in process_collection(self, collection)
   1537         self._nodeStack.append([])
   1538         self._builderStack.append(builder)
-> 1539         builder.process_collection(collection)
   1540         added_nodes = self._nodeStack.pop()
   1541         self._nodeStack[-1].extend(added_nodes)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py in process_collection(self, collection)
   1828         """
   1829         for item in collection:
-> 1830             self._base_builder.process_collection(item)
   1831 
   1832     def apply_rules(self):

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py in process_collection(self, collection)
   1531         # just a step?
   1532         if isinstance(collection, PipelineStep):
-> 1533             return self.process_step(collection)
   1534 
   1535         # delegate to correct builder

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/builder.py in process_step(self, step)
   1575             return self._step2node[step]
   1576 
-> 1577         node = step.create_node(self._graph, self._default_datastore, self._context)
   1578         self.assert_node_valid(step, self._graph, node)
   1579 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/steps/hyper_drive_step.py in create_node(self, graph, default_datastore, context)
    247         """
    248         hyperdrive_config, reuse_hashable_config = self._get_hyperdrive_config(context._workspace,
--> 249                                                                                context._experiment_name)
    250         self._params[HyperDriveStep._run_config_param_name] = json.dumps(hyperdrive_config)
    251         self._params[HyperDriveStep._run_reuse_hashable_config] = json.dumps(reuse_hashable_config)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/steps/hyper_drive_step.py in _get_hyperdrive_config(self, workspace, experiment_name)
    323 
    324         hyperdrive_dto = _search._create_experiment_dto(self._hyperdrive_config, workspace,
--> 325                                                         experiment_name, telemetry_values)
    326 
    327         hyperdrive_config = hyperdrive_dto.as_dict()

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/train/hyperdrive/_search.py in _create_experiment_dto(hyperdrive_config, workspace, experiment_name, telemetry_values, activity_logger, **kwargs)
     41     if hyperdrive_config.source_directory is not None:
     42         snapshot_client = SnapshotsClient(workspace.service_context)
---> 43         snapshot_id = snapshot_client.create_snapshot(hyperdrive_config.source_directory)
     44 
     45         if activity_logger is not None:

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/snapshots_client.py in create_snapshot(self, file_or_folder_path, retry_on_failure, raise_on_validation_failure)
     83         exclude_function = ignore_file.is_file_excluded
     84 
---> 85         self._validate_snapshot_size(file_or_folder_path, exclude_function, raise_on_validation_failure)
     86 
     87         # Get the previous snapshot for this project

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/snapshots_client.py in _validate_snapshot_size(self, file_or_folder_path, exclude_function, raise_on_validation_failure)
     61                             "\n".format(file_or_folder_path, SNAPSHOT_MAX_SIZE_BYTES / ONE_MB)
     62             if raise_on_validation_failure:
---> 63                 raise SnapshotException(error_message)
     64             else:
     65                 self._logger.warning(error_message)

SnapshotException: SnapshotException:
    Message: ====================================================================

While attempting to take snapshot of ./train/
Your total snapshot size exceeds the limit of 0.00095367431640625 MB.
Please see http://aka.ms/aml-largefiles on how to work with large files.

====================================================================


    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "====================================================================\n\nWhile attempting to take snapshot of ./train/\nYour total snapshot size exceeds the limit of 0.00095367431640625 MB.\nPlease see http://aka.ms/aml-largefiles on how to work with large files.\n\n====================================================================\n\n"
    }
}
```

Any idea how I fix this?

The fulls script is here: [Script at Github](https://github.com/MichaelSoegaard/AzureML_Health_Insurace_Cross_Sell/blob/main/Custom_hyperparameter_tuning.ipynb)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I found the fix.

I changed this line by adding a number equvilant to 1GB: `azureml._restclient.snapshots_client.SNAPSHOT_MAX_SIZE_BYTES = 1000000000`

For some reason, you have to define the size in BYTES and not megabytes even though the default is 300 MB. Not especially intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @Capt_Bender this solved my problem

Just as FYI for others, the import statement that worked for me was:

```py
import azureml._restclient.snapshots_client
azureml._restclient.snapshots_client.SNAPSHOT_MAX_SIZE_BYTES = 1000000000
```